# "object 'merPredDb' not found" error in ggpredict

Tags: r, ggplot2, glmm

I am trying to plot the predicted data with ggpredict() and having an error "Error in object@pp$b(1) : object 'merPredDb' not found":

> glmmdata3.17_predict <- ggpredict(glmmdata3.17,
> terms="days_cnt2[all]",type = "re")
> Error in object@pp$b(1) : object 'merPredDb' not found

My model was built using glmer(), and the data is huge with 820k cases. Could anyone please point out where I did wrong?

Comment: What you are passing to `terms` doesn't look right.

Comment: In what way? The terms should describe what should be on the x-axis, and in my case it's the variable days_cnt2, which is numeric.

Comment: Solved! glmmdata3.17_predict <- ggpredict(glmmdata3.17, terms=c("days_cnt2")) worked.  It seems the "re" option does not work.  Thanks Roland!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `days_cnt2[all]` is not a variable in the model.

Comment: I don't get it. How do you know?

Comment: I know because term names usually don't contain subsetting operators.

Comment: I put the subsetting operator [] because I got the following message: "Data were 'prettified'. Consider using `terms="days_cnt2 [all]"` to get smooth plots."

Comment: OK, so it might work. But why did you omit the blank space bevor `[all]` in your code?

Comment: well, it's just my mistake ...